# Bernoulli random variables and two player games

Tags: random-variables, game-theory, mathematical-modeling

With hockey playoffs upon us, I have been thinking about ways of modeling the results of athletic events.

Suppose team A wins 50% of its games against average teams, and team B wins 50% of its games against average teams (i.e. two average teams play). Then we expect team A wins 50% of the time and team B wins 50% of the time. That is, the game is a fair coin flip, a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $p = 0.5$.

Now suppose team A wins 60% of its games against average teams, and team B wins 50% of its games against average teams (i.e. team B is average). Then we expect team A wins 60% of the time and team B wins 40% of the time. This is again a Bernoulli random variable, but now $p = 0.6$.

Now suppose team A wins 60% of its games against average teams, and team B wins 30% of its games against average teams. I figure the outcome of this game should again be a Bernoulli random variable, but I am unsure of how to calculate $p$ in this case. Is my modeling framework too simplistic here? Do I need more information about team A and team B to draw a meaningful conclusion? I think I may need to assume how the team performances are distributed to come to an answer, but I'm not sure.

Apologies if my question is ill-posed or overly simplistic. I know lots of people do this kind of modelling professionally (albeit using much more complicated models), but it's a subject I don't know much about.

Comment: What is an “average team?” Can you consider either team to be “average” in the A-B match?

Comment: An average team would be one that wins 50% of its games against other average teams (yes I know that is self referential). In the first example I gave, both teams are exactly average. In the second example, team A is better than average and team B is average. In the third example, team A is better than average and team B is worse than average.

Comment: Well, if neither team is “average,” then you can’t really use their statistics vs. average teams, can you? You can certainly make an initial estimate of the probabilities based on their overall records, but to be more accurate you should examine their records vs. each other.

Comment: Head to head record is a pretty small sample size. My idea is to estimate the strength of each team relative to league average (which isn't too hard, obviously there are various philosophies on how to do it though), and then use that. I just am unsure how to translate that information into an appropriate Bernoulli parameter for a game between two teams.

Comment: Might as well take their overall win records and then scale so that the sum of the probabilities is $1$. As you get more information, you can use Bayes’ theorem to update the estimate.

Comment: Here's the thing though. I'm assuming that every team in a league, over the course of a season, faces the same average quality of competition. So suppose team A wins 60% of their games, and team B wins 40% of their games. Does that mean we expect in games between teams A and B for team A to win 60% of the time? No. Team A is stronger than the league average, and team B is weaker than the league average, so we expect team A to win more than 60% of the time, since they are facing weaker competition than average. This is what I am unsure of how to account for.